ExtJS TreeMap visulation
I am creating TreeMap visualation in ExtJS. If the tree has following tree structure
Root has two children A & B, each A & B has two children AA,AAA, BB,BBB
Root
A
AA
AAA
B
BB
BB
Default behavior is when node A is expanded , it does not collapse the node B but i am looking the behavior when node A is expanded , B gets collapse and when node B is expanded, node A should collapse,
Ext.application({
name: 'fiddle',
launch: function () {

    var SegTreeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        type: 'tree',
        root: {
            expanded: true,
            children: [{
                text: 'GATE A 30',
                value: 3,
                expanded: false,
                children: [{
                    text: 'The Leader',
                    value: 3,
                    expanded: false,
                    children: [{
                        text: 'The 2nd Leader',
                        value: 1,
                        leaf: true
                    }]
                }, {
                    text: 'Abomination',
                    value: 2,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Sandman',
                    value: 1,
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }, {
                text: 'Vision',
                value: 40,
                expanded: false,
                children: [{
                    text: 'Kang',
                    value: 3,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Magneto',
                    value: 4,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Norman Osborn',
                    value: 5,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Anti-Vision',
                    value: 7,
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }, {
                text: 'Ghost Rider',
                value: 3,
                expanded: false,
                children: [{
                    text: 'Mephisto',
                    value: 1,
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }, {
                text: 'Loki',
                value: 2,
                expanded: false,
                children: [{
                    text: 'Captain America',
                    value: 3,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Deadpool',
                    value: 4,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Odin',
                    value: 5,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Scarlet Witch',
                    value: 2,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Silver Surfer',
                    value: 1,
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }, {
                text: 'Daredevil',
                value: 1,
                expanded: false,
                children: [{
                    text: 'Purple Man',
                    value: 4,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Kingpin',
                    value: 3,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Namor',
                    value: 2,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Sabretooth',
                    value: 1,
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }]
        }
    });

    var SegTreeStore3 = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        type: 'tree',
        root: {
            expanded: true,
            children: [{
                text: 'Daredevil',
                value: 1,
                expanded: false,
                children: [{
                    text: 'Purple Man',
                    value: 4,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Kingpin',
                    value: 3,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Namor',
                    value: 2,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Sabretooth',
                    value: 1,
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }]
        }
    });

    var SegTreeStore2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        type: 'tree',
        root: {
            expanded: true,
            children: [{
                text: 'GATE A 30',
                value: 3,
                expanded: true,
                children: [{
                    text: 'The Leader',
                    value: 3,
                    expanded: false,
                    children: [{
                        text: 'The 2nd Leader',
                        value: 1,
                        leaf: true
                    }]
                }, {
                    text: 'Abomination',
                    value: 2,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Sandman',
                    value: 1,
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }]
        }
    });

    var SegTreeStore1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        type: 'tree',
        root: {
            expanded: true,
            children: [{
                text: 'Vision',
                value: 40,
                expanded: false,
                children: [{
                    text: 'Kang',
                    value: 10,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Magneto',
                    value: 12,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Norman Osborn',
                    value: 12,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Anti-Vision',
                    value: 17,
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }]
        }
    });

    function createSegTreeStore3(originalStore,selectedNodeText,selectedNodeIsExpanded) {
        // Find the 'Daredevil' node in the original store
        var daredevilNode = null;
        originalStore.getRootNode().eachChild(function (child) {
            if (child.get('text') === selectedNodeText) {

                daredevilNode = child.copy(undefined,true); // Make a copy of the node
                //daredevilNode.data.expanded = selectedNodeIsExpanded;
                return false; // Stop the loop
            }
        });

        if (daredevilNode) {
            // Create the new store with the 'Daredevil' node
            return Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
                type: 'tree',
                root: {
                    expanded: true,
                    children:[{
                        text: daredevilNode.get('text'),
                        value: daredevilNode.get('value'),
                        expanded: daredevilNode.get('expanded'),
                        children: Ext.clone(daredevilNode.get('children'))
                    }]
                    //children: [daredevilNode.data]
                    //children : Ext.clone(daredevilNode.data)
                }
            });
        }

        return null;
    }

    function updateValues(node, selectedNodeText) {
        if (node.text !== selectedNodeText) {
            node.value = 0;
        }
        if (node.children) {
            node.children.forEach(child => updateValues(child, selectedNodeText));
        }
    }

    function updateNodeValues(node, newValue, selectedNodeText, selectedNodeDepth) {
        console.log(node);
        if (node.text != selectedNodeText && node.depth == selectedNodeDepth) {
            node.value = 0;
        }

        if (node.children) {

            node.children.forEach(child => updateNodeValues(child, newValue, selectedNodeText, selectedNodeDepth));
        }
        //node.value = newValue;
    }

    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        title: 'TreeMap Chart',
        id: 'Test_TreeMap',
        height: 750,
        width: 750,
        layout: 'fit',

        items: [{
            xtype: 'd3-treemap',
            //autoLoad: true,

            nodeValue: function (record) {
                // The value in your data to derive the size of the tile from.
                return record.get('value');
            },
            store: SegTreeStore,

            listeners: {
                element: 'element',
                dblclick: function (event, target) {
                    var tempTreeStore = SegTreeStore;
                    console.log(tempTreeStore);

                    console.log(target.__data__.data.data.text);
                    var selectedNodeText = target.__data__.data.data.text;
                    var selectedNodeIsExpanded = target.__data__.data.data.expanded;
                    var selectedNodeDepth = target.__data__.data.data.depth;

                    var textToChildrenMap = {
                        "Root": [{
                            text: 'GATE A 30',
                            value: 5,
                            expanded: true,
                            children: [{
                                text: 'The Leader',
                                value: 3,
                                expanded: false,
                                children: [{
                                    text: 'The 2nd Leader',
                                    value: 1,
                                    leaf: true
                                }]
                            }, {
                                text: 'Abomination',
                                value: 2,
                                leaf: true
                            }, {
                                text: 'Sandman',
                                value: 1,
                                leaf: true
                            }]
                        }, {
                            text: 'Vision',
                            value: 4,
                            expanded: false,
                            children: [{
                                text: 'Kang',
                                value: 4,
                                leaf: true
                            }, {
                                text: 'Magneto',
                                value: 3,
                                leaf: true
                            }, {
                                text: 'Norman Osborn',
                                value: 2,
                                leaf: true
                            }, {
                                text: 'Anti-Vision',
                                value: 1,
                                leaf: true
                            }]
                        }, {
                            text: 'Ghost Rider',
                            value: 3,
                            expanded: false,
                            children: [{
                                text: 'Mephisto',
                                value: 1,
                                leaf: true
                            }]
                        }, {
                            text: 'Loki',
                            value: 2,
                            expanded: false,
                            children: [{
                                text: 'Captain America',
                                value: 3,
                                leaf: true
                            }, {
                                text: 'Deadpool',
                                value: 4,
                                leaf: true
                            }, {
                                text: 'Odin',
                                value: 5,
                                leaf: true
                            }, {
                                text: 'Scarlet Witch',
                                value: 2,
                                leaf: true
                            }, {
                                text: 'Silver Surfer',
                                value: 1,
                                leaf: true
                            }]
                        }, {
                            text: 'Daredevil',
                            value: 1,
                            expanded: false,
                            children: [{
                                text: 'Purple Man',
                                value: 4,
                                leaf: true
                            }, {
                                text: 'Kingpin',
                                value: 3,
                                leaf: true
                            }, {
                                text: 'Namor',
                                value: 2,
                                leaf: true
                            }, {
                                text: 'Sabretooth',
                                value: 1,
                                leaf: true
                            }]
                        }],
                        "GATE A 30": [{
                            text: 'The Leader',
                            value: 3,
                            expanded: false,
                            children: [{
                                text: 'The 2nd Leader',
                                value: 1,
                                leaf: true
                            }]
                        }, {
                            text: 'Abomination',
                            value: 2,
                            leaf: true
                        }, {
                            text: 'Sandman',
                            value: 1,
                            leaf: true
                        }],
                        "Vision": [{
                            text: 'Kang',
                            value: 4,
                            leaf: true
                        }, {
                            text: 'Magneto',
                            value: 3,
                            leaf: true
                        }, {
                            text: 'Norman Osborn',
                            value: 2,
                            leaf: true
                        }, {
                            text: 'Anti-Vision',
                            value: 1,
                            leaf: true
                        }],
                        "Ghost Rider": [{
                            text: 'Mephisto',
                            value: 1,
                            leaf: true
                        }],
                        "Loki": [{
                            text: 'Captain America',
                            value: 3,
                            leaf: true
                        }, {
                            text: 'Deadpool',
                            value: 4,
                            leaf: true
                        }, {
                            text: 'Odin',
                            value: 5,
                            leaf: true
                        }, {
                            text: 'Scarlet Witch',
                            value: 2,
                            leaf: true
                        }, {
                            text: 'Silver Surfer',
                            value: 1,
                            leaf: true
                        }],
                        "Daredevil": [{
                            text: 'Purple Man',
                            value: 4,
                            leaf: true
                        }, {
                            text: 'Kingpin',
                            value: 3,
                            leaf: true
                        }, {
                            text: 'Namor',
                            value: 2,
                            leaf: true
                        }, {
                            text: 'Sabretooth',
                            value: 1,
                            leaf: true
                        }],
                        "The Leader": [{
                            text: 'The 2nd Leader',
                            value: 1,
                            leaf: true
                        }]
                    };

                    // Update values in the entire tree

                    var SegTreeStore5 = createSegTreeStore3(this.component.getStore(),selectedNodeText,selectedNodeIsExpanded);

                    console.log("Filtering daredevils !!!!");
                    console.log(SegTreeStore5);
                    console.log(SegTreeStore);
                    console.log(SegTreeStore1);
                    console.log(SegTreeStore2);
                    console.log(SegTreeStore3);
                    //console.log(SegTreeStore4);
                    if (selectedNodeText == "Root"){
                        this.component.setStore(SegTreeStore);
                    }else{
                        this.component.setStore(SegTreeStore5);
                    }
                    /*if (selectedNodeText == "Vision") {
                        this.component.setStore(SegTreeStore1);
                    } else if (selectedNodeText == "Daredevil") {
                        this.component.setStore(SegTreeStore3);
                    } else if ((selectedNodeText == "GATE A 30")) {
                        this.component.setStore(SegTreeStore2);
                    } else {
                        this.component.setStore(SegTreeStore)
                    }*/

                }
            }
        }]
    });

}

});
